# Cosa significa "consistere" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto :

> Non c'era che da prevedere cose semplici, inevitabili e insopportabili, tutta quella polvere di Porta a Prato dove le vetture torneavano in una nuvola bianca soffocante e i viaggiatori salivano e scendevano quasi già avvolti dalle nebbie della distanza e già irriconoscibili, in un frastuono di gerghi ultramontani, di urlaci toscani: e mosche sui cavalli sudati e rotolar di mercanzie e bagagli;  dove i piedi di chi si fermava a guardare, a salutare, non sapevano dove *consistere*.

Ho cercato il significato del verbo "consistere" in alcuni dizionari. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cosa vuol dire che "i piedi non sapevano dove consistere". Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il verbo *consistere* viene dal latino *cum* + *sistĕre*. A sua volta *sistĕre* è un intensivo di *stare* e significa *fermarsi*.

Sul Treccani c'è un esempio da Guicciardini

> terre … che … verso il polo meridionale consistono

nel senso di *trovarsi*, *stare*.

Nel passo in esame, i piedi non sanno trovare una posizione stabile perché il movimento della folla trascina chiunque cerchi di fermarsi.

Come spesso accade, le parole acquistano significati traslati rispetto a quello etimologico e *consistere* si adopera in genere per dire *avere fondamento* o simili. Anna Banti era fiorentina e il lessico toscano, fiorentino in particolare, ha termini che altrove suonano quanto meno strani.

Comment: Vedo che in [questo vocabolario dell'ottocento della Accademia della Crusca](https://books.google.es/books?id=3PwsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA767&lpg=PA767&dq=consistere) appare anche l'accezione "essere situato", che viene accompagnata dello stesso esempio che hai menzionato.

Answer (score 1):

"Consistere" solitamente viene usato col significato di "**costituito da**".

es: *Questa frase consiste in una serie di parole.*

Tuttavia in questo caso assume il significato di "**trovare consistenza** (solidità)", riferendosi al pavimento.

Answer (score 1):

Penso che qui il termine [consistere](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/consistere.php) sia usato in senso più arcaico, forse dialettale di:

> - (ant.) Avere stabilità. (Hoepli)
> - (ant.) Reggersi.  (Treccani)

- Il riferimento è ad una scena caotica dove gli astanti non sanno dove "consistere" ossia dove stare, dove mettere i piedi.

Comment: In effetti, dato che l'azione si situa nella prima metà del seicento, Anna Banti usa molti arcaismi in questo romanzo.